# Firebase Firestore: Could not reach Firestore backend (Android only)

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, create-react-native-app

I'm building a `react-native` app using `Create React Native App`. For the backend it uses `Firebase Firestore`. The app works fine on iOS but fails with the following error on Android (both with simulator and on a device) when trying to fetch data from the backend:

```
22:02:37: [2018-05-22T05:02:33.751Z]  @firebase/firestore:, Firestore (4.10.1): Could not reach Firestore backend.
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\YellowBox.js:71:16 in error
- node_modules\@firebase\logger\dist\cjs\src\logger.js:97:25 in defaultLogHandler
- ... 18 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Any idea what can be the problem and how to debug this?

The error seems to be a generic, as there are other questions with the same error message. But in this case it's specific to Android only.

Full log and the stack trace:

```
21:50:51: Warning: Expo version in package.json does not match sdkVersion in manifest.
21:50:51:
21:50:51: If there is an issue running your project, please run `npm install` in C:\Users\grigor\Documents\Bitbucket\AwesomeProject and restart.
21:51:08: Finished building JavaScript bundle in 26098ms
21:51:14: Running app on XT1053 in development mode

21:51:34: [2018-05-25T04:51:26.597Z]  @firebase/firestore:, Firestore (4.10.1): Could not reach Firestore backend.
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\YellowBox.js:71:16 in error
- node_modules\@firebase\logger\dist\cjs\src\logger.js:97:25 in defaultLogHandler
- ... 18 more stack frames from framework internals
21:51:37: Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.
(Saw setTimeout with duration 3299464ms)
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\YellowBox.js:82:15 in warn
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:254:8 in setTimeout
- node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:37:577 in Hc
* null:null in <unknown>
- node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:15:932 in y
- node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:37:606 in Ic
- node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:210:0 in kk
- node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:209:665 in start
- node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:215:38 in Dk
- node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:253:425 in ql
- node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:255:146 in <unknown>
- node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:19:220 in <unknown>
* null:null in Gb
* null:null in Cb
- node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:22:103 in Sb
- node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:15:643 in jb
- ... 10 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Comment: can you provide the details stacktrace of terminal when you try to build app for android .

Comment: @Prince added stack trace to the post

Comment: please do this, In your React Native project, navigate to android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml. Verify that the manifest->package attribute matches what's in your google-services.json file under client_info->android_client_info->package_name.

or you can follow https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/638 that may help you with the issue.

Comment: @Prince this is a expo app created with create-react-native-app command, there is no android directory

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact solution for the problem, but I realised that the way in which I was interacting with `firebase` made my application more susceptible. Maybe you can spot some of my own design flaws in your project?

What I've found is that I was calling `initializeApp` outside of a `try/catch`, which meant that the entire JavaScript module would fail whenever the error is encountered. So, the first work around is to properly handle initialization safely.

Secondly, this error became prominent in the way in which I structured my my calls to `firestore()`. For example, my first call to `firebase.firestore()` was embedded within a method that returned a `Promise`, i.e.:

`() => firebase.firestore().collection('someCollection').get().then(...).catch(e => ...);`

Now, with this approach, if the interaction with `firestore` failed before a `Promise` could be returned, we don't actually `catch` the error! This is because it occurs too early in the chain for a `Promise` to be created. This meant that again, the application would appear to  fail at apparently some much deeper level than something that could be caught inside the application. But that's wrong!

The correct implementation would be to wrap the interaction with `firebase.firestore()` within a `Promise` first:

`return new Promise(resolve => firebase.firestore().collection(...)).then(q => ...).catch(e =>...);`

Hope this helps in some way. I know it's a tricky problem!